# How can I dynamically place a "floating action button" between two seams?

Tags: html, css, layout, material-design, floating-action-button

I´d like to know how I can place a "floating action button" as Google calls it [(Reference: Floating Action Button, Google Material Design)](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html) dynamically between two "seams" - depending on the element it is placed in.

In my case I use simple HTML container classes with few CSS rules to create Google Cards.

[image]

The HTML and CSS Code I used here looks like the following:

```css
/* Google Material Design (Paper-) Cards */
*.card {
 position: relative;

 border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;

 color: var(--grey800);
 background-color: var(--grey50);
}
*.card .card-header {
 position:relative;

 padding: 20px 16px;

 border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
}
*.card .card-header > span.card-title {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}
*.card .card-header > span.card-subtitle {
 display: block;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 color: var(--grey700);
}
*.card .rich-media {
  position: relative;
}
*.card .rich-media > img {
  display: block;

  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  width: 100%;

  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
}
*.card .card-header ~ .rich-media > img {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
}

*.card .rich-media > span.card-title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  padding: 20px 16px;

  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--white);
}
*.card .card-content {
  padding: 20px 16px;
}
*.card .card-content + .card-content {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
}

*.card .card-action {
 position: relative;

 padding: 20px 16px;

 border-top: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);

 border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;

 background-color: inherit;
}
*.card .card-action > a {
 transition: color .3s ease;

 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: var(--orange500);
}
*.card .card-action > a:hover {
 color: var(--orange200);
}

/* Google Material Design Buttons */
*.btn {
 /* ... */
}
*.floating-action {
 width: 56px;
 height: 56px;
 
 text-align: center;
 
 border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
*.floating-action .material-icons {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-elevation="1">
  <!-- card header -->
  <div class="card-header">
    <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
    <span class="card-subtitle">Card Subtitle</span>
  </div>
  <!-- card image  -->
  <div class="rich-media">
    <image src="mountains.jpg"></image>
  </div>
  <!-- card content -->
  <div class="card-content align-left">
    <!-- floating action button -->
    <div class="floating-action bg-orange500" data-elevation="2">
      <i class="material-icons txt-white">mail_outline</i>
    </div>
    <p class="flowtext">
      The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- card actions -->
  <div class="card-action">
    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to approach is a way of placing the seen button (the little one with the envelope icon on it) between (the previous) two contiguous borders like shown with a red dot below:

[image]

It is also possible to add multiple content containers; In this case the placed buttons should also be placed between the previous contiguous container borders.

[image]

In the last case shown above the button would be placed inside the 2nd card-container element.

Maybe some jQuery calculation would help. What do you think? What is a good practice to achieve the required layout?

Answer (score 1):

In this Page: http://materializecss.com/cards.html you can access cards examples and one of them is placing the `FAB` button between title and content of the card. All you have to do is to see the CSS they show in source code.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
          <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red">
             <i class="material-icons">add</i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


.btn-floating.btn-large i {
    line-height: 56px;
}

.btn-large i {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.btn-floating i {
    width: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.btn-floating.btn-large.halfway-fab {
    bottom: -28px;
}

.btn-floating.halfway-fab {
    position: absolute;
    right: 24px;
    bottom: -20px;
}
.btn-floating.btn-large {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    padding: 0;
}
```